# Unit test not working correctly when comparing collections

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I have a very simple method which queries the database and returns a value. The code is as follows:

```
public List<int?> TravelTime()
{
   List<int?> items = new List<int?>();
   Induction induction = new Induction();
   using (var dbContext = new MyEntites())
   {
     var query = dbContext.MyTable.Select(a => a.Travel_Time).Take(1);

      foreach (var item in query)
      {
        induction.TravelTime = item;
        items.Add(induction.TravelTime);
      }
   }
   return items;// Value here is 8
}
```

I'm trying to unit test this method with the following code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Check_Travel_Time_Test()
{
  //Arrange
  InductionView vModel = new InductionView();
  Induction induction = new Induction();
  List<int?> actual = new List<int?>();
  induction.TravelTime = 8;
  actual.Add(induction.TravelTime);

  //Act
  var expected = vModel.TravelTime();

  //Assert
  Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

I don't know why it's not passing. The exception I get is.

Expected:`<System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Nullable'1[System.Int32]]>.`

Actual:`<System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Nullable'1[System.Int32]]>`.

If I debug I have the correct values and count is 1 in My `TravelMethod` and Test method. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: AreEqual compares the references not the contents

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Assert.AreEqual* compares references, not the content. You need to use *[CollectionAssert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx)* class and its methods, like *CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent*

Comment: Right, I got you.. Thanks for this. I'll accept it as soon as the time limit is up